# How portable is weak linking? #pragma weak my_symbol

Tags: c, gcc, linker, portability, weak-linking

How portable is weak linking?

```
#pragma weak my_symbol
```

I see that question:  [how-to-make-weak-linking-work-with-gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274753/how-to-make-weak-linking-work-with-gcc) discusses how to get it working. But is there a good way to do this such that gcc is not required?

What is the difference between weak linking and guarding the declartion with an #ifdef?

```
#ifndef my_weak_fn
    void my_weak_fn(){/* Do nothing */ return;}
#endif
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`#pragma` is, by definition, *not* portable.

And weak linking is done at link time (surprisingly enough). It allows a function (or any symbol, really) with the same signature to override another. That means a strong one will be chosen in preference to the weak one but, if there's no strong one, the weak one will be used.

Include guards are done by the compiler, not the linker, and they do *not* allow the fallback to a weak one if the strong one's not there. You can simulate the same behavior if you control the source for both functions (by `ifdef`-ing for one, `ifndef`-ing for the other) but that's not always the case and this is more choosing between two strong functions.

Weak linking allows you to do things like drop in your own `malloc()/free()` for debugging purposes while still linking with the library that provides them.