# Why redefinition of a function which is already present in dynamic or static library does not throw any error?

Tags: c, linker-errors, duplicate-symbol

Wy redefinition of function already present in dynamic library does not throws any compilation and linking error?

In the below function

```
#include "calc_mean.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int mean(int t, int v) {
  return 0;
}

int main () {
  int theMean = mean(3,6);
  printf("\n  %d\n",theMean);
}
```

Inside the shared library Definition of mean function already present as below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "calc_mean.h"

int mean(int a, int b) {
  return (a+b)/2;
}
```

The definition of mean function is already present in the shared library `libmean.so`. But during compilation I don't see any redefinition error and compilation is successful.

And on successful execution the o/p I see is 0 instead of 4 so the function definition of mean inside the shared library is not getting executed but the one inside the main module is getting executed.

Why is this happening so?

Comment: Why shoiuld it throw an error?

Comment: You always can redifined your shared lib functions, the source code is prio on compilation.

Comment: But as the definition of the function is already present in the shared library and we are linking the main program along with the shared library .So redefining a function already defined in the library should throw a error .

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089166/how-to-make-gcc-link-strong-symbol-in-static-library-to-overwittren-weak-symbol

Answer (score 7):

The linker only links in a function from a library if the function had not yet been found during the compilation/linking process.

The reason for the difference in functionality is that there are different types of symbols. A library function is a weak symbol. It is only included if it is not already defined. `nm` is a tool for listing the symbols in an object or executable. In its [man-page](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.17/binutils/nm.html#nm) you can find a list of the types of symbols.

There is also a wikipedia page on [weak symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol).

Comment: Why is it that `nm -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`tells me that `puts` is `W`, `printf` is `T`, but I can redefined both in a program with GCC? This makes it look like being weak (in the ELF sense) is not the question.

Answer (score 1):

Having two definitions of one externally-visible function (even if the definitions are identical, for non-inline functions) causes undefined behaviour, with no diagnostic required. (Ref: C99 6.9#5 and Annex J.2)

In C, some illegal code requires a compiler diagnostic and some doesn't. Typically the ones that do not require a diagnostic are because:

- it would be considered too prohibitive to require all compilers to detect and report the error
- there were existing systems in use that did not diagnose it and the Standard committee did not want to render an existing implementation non-conforming.

In this case, my guess would be that this is a case of the first one; they wanted to leave open the option for compilers/linkers to implement *weak symbols* as an extension, so they did not specify that the compiler must give a warning here.   Or possibly it is actually difficult to detect this in general, I've never tried to write a linker!

It should be considered a quality-of-implementation issue if no diagnostic is given. Perhaps it is possible to pass different flags to your linker so that it does reject this code; if not then you could put a in bug report or a feature request.

Answer (score -2):

Did you link correctly the shared library because the compiler should give the error :

multiple definition of 'mean'