# Hijacking a function's implementation by linking another object file

Tags: c++, object, implementation

I've heard that it is possible to override / hijack / hack a function's implementation by linking against the object file the function resides in with another one that you authored. I've been playing around, and it seems like I can only get this to work in one situation. However, I was wondering if it's possible to achieve this result (shown below) in other situations besides the one described.

Compiler used: TDM-GCC 4.9.2

OS: Windows 8 64-bit

The following describes the situation where hijacking is "successful":

Here's a sample source called `sample.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

int returnOne();

int main()
{
    std::cout << "returnOne() returns " << returnOne();

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation:

```
g++ -c sample.cpp -o sample.o
```

After checking the object file with `nm.exe`, my function's mangled name is: `__Z9returnOnev`

So, off into another source `hack.cpp`:

```
extern "C" int _Z9returnOnev()
{
    return 5;  //rather than return 1
}
```

Compilation:

```
g++ -c hack.cpp -o hack.o
```

Now I "recreate" the executable with the `hack.o` file:

```
g++ -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition hack.o sample.o -o sample.exe
```

When ran, `sample.exe` produces:

```
returnOne() returns 5
```

So the hijack was successful.

Now, if at any point do I provide the implementation of `returnOne()` in the original source, this technique no longer works. As in:

```
#include <iostream>

int returnOne();

int main()
{
    std::cout << "returnOne() returns " << returnOne();

    return 0;
}

int returnOne()
{
    return 1;
}
```

It compiles fine, but when invoked, the function uses the original implementation every time.

So, I'm wondering if it's possible to "hijack" a function's implementation in this fashion if it's implementation is already defined in the original source, or is only possible if only it's prototype is defined?

---

Edit (7/15/15):
I also compiled w/o optimizations, as in:

```
g++ -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition,-O0 hack.o sample.o -o sample.exe
```

However, the problem persists.

---

Edit2 (7/15/15):
Ok, I cleaned, then compiled and linked everything w/ the -O0 switch:

```
g++ -O0 -c sample.cpp -o sample.o

g++ -O0 -c hack.cpp -o hack.o

g++ -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition,-O0 hack.o sample.o -o sample.exe
```

It's still returning 1.

Comment: The function was most probably inlined by the compiler. Try disabling all optimizations.

Comment: I tried the linker option -O0, so my new invocation was:
    `g++ -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition,-O0 hack.o sample.o -o sample.exe`
But it produced the same effect.

Comment: @PaulRich you need to use the `-O0` option when compiling sample.cpp: `g++ -O0 -c sample.cpp -o sample.o`.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089166/how-to-make-gcc-link-strong-symbol-in-static-library-to-overwrite-weak-symbol

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to override the function implementation in that case.

What your compiler usually does when it compiles a source file is that it creates a table with function signatures (identifier + parameter types) and function addresses. 
When you have a function invocation in your code, the compiler tries to call the function with this signature. 
This is why you need a linker - the #include statement actually copies all the declarations into your code before compiling so that you have the right signatures. The linker then adds the address of the callable function. 
If you have a function definition in your main.cpp, there is no need for the compiler/linker to look up a definition anywhere else.