# GCC behavior for unresolved weak functions

Tags: c, gcc, arm, ld, weak

Consider the simple program below:

```
__attribute__((weak)) void weakf(void);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        weakf();
}
```

When compiling this with gcc and running it on a Linux PC, it segfaults. When running it on ARM CM0 (arm-none-eabi-gcc), the linker replace the undefined symbol by a jump to the following instruction and a nop.

Where is this behavior documented? Is there possible ways to change it through command line options? I have been through [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/gcc/) and [LD](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.25/ld/index.html) documentations, there is no information about that.

If I check the ARM compiler doc however, [this is clearly explained](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0474e/CACCEEIF.html).

Answer (score 5):

**`man nm`**

I was reading some docs and happened to come across a related quote for this:

```
man nm
```

says:

> "V"
>   "v" The symbol is a weak object.  When a weak defined symbol is linked with a normal defined symbol, the normal defined symbol is used with no error.  When a weak undefined symbol is linked and
>              the symbol is not defined, the value of the weak symbol becomes zero with no error.  On some systems, uppercase indicates that a default value has been specified.
>
> "W"
>   "w" The symbol is a weak symbol that has not been specifically tagged as a weak object symbol.  When a weak defined symbol is linked with a normal defined symbol, the normal defined symbol is
>              used with no error.  When a weak undefined symbol is linked and the symbol is not defined, the value of the symbol is determined in a system-specific manner without error.  On some systems,
>              uppercase indicates that a default value has been specified.

`nm` is part of Binutils, which GCC uses under the hood, so this should be canonical enough.

Then, example on your source file:

main.c

```
__attribute__((weak)) void weakf(void);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        weakf();
}
```

we do:

```
gcc -O0 -ggdb3 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.c
nm main.out
```

which contains:

```
w weakf
```

and so it is a system-specific value. I can't find where the per-system behavior is defined however. I don't think you can do better than reading Binutils source here.

`v` would be fixed to 0, but that is used for undefined variables (which are objects): [How to make weak linking work with GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274753/how-to-make-weak-linking-work-with-gcc/54601464#54601464)

Then:

```
gdb -batch -ex 'disassemble/rs main' main.out
```

gives:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
main.c:
4       {
   0x0000000000001135 <+0>:     55      push   %rbp
   0x0000000000001136 <+1>:     48 89 e5        mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000001139 <+4>:     48 83 ec 10     sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x000000000000113d <+8>:     89 7d fc        mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x0000000000001140 <+11>:    48 89 75 f0     mov    %rsi,-0x10(%rbp)

5               weakf();
   0x0000000000001144 <+15>:    e8 e7 fe ff ff  callq  0x1030 <weakf@plt>
   0x0000000000001149 <+20>:    b8 00 00 00 00  mov    $0x0,%eax

6       }
   0x000000000000114e <+25>:    c9      leaveq 
   0x000000000000114f <+26>:    c3      retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

which means it gets [resolved at the PLT](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1992/what-is-plt-got/20214#20214).

Then since I don't fully understand PLT, I experimentally verify that it resolves to address 0 and segfaults:

```
gdb -nh -ex run -ex bt main.out
```

I'm supposing the same happens on ARM, it must just set it to 0 as well.

Answer (score 1):

On ARM with gcc this code does not work for me (test on armv7 with gcc Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1). It looks like the arm compiler toolchain has a different behavior.

I do not found useful documentation for this behavior. It seems that the weakf equals NULL if it's undefine at link time.

So I sugest you to test it:

```
if (weakf == NULL) printf ("weakf not found\n");
else weakf();
```

Comment: I am looking for the official behavior from the doc, not for any workaround

Comment: I know but this feature is not a part of the C standard and its look like many GCC's features not enough documented.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes
` 
weak
    The weak attribute causes the declaration to be emitted as a weak symbol rather than a global. This is primarily useful in defining library functions that can be overridden in user code, though it can also be used with non-function declarations. Weak symbols are supported for ELF targets, and also for a.out targets when using the GNU assembler and linker.
`