# Provide fallback symbol for dynamic linking

Tags: ios, linux, gcc, ld, dynamic-linking

When dynamically linking a library is there a way to specify a fallback symbol in case one is missing at load time.

For example compiling a MEX file instead of `mxCreateNumericArray` I'd like to call `mxCreateUninitNumericArray` (with same signature). But the latter won't be present for older MATLAB versions. Same for `mxArrayToString` and `mxArrayToUTF8String`.

For MSVC I've been able to use /DELAYLOAD and hook into `__pfnDliFailureHook2` on `dliFailGetProc` to provide a simple mapping. But what can I do on Unix based systems?

How to hook into `libld` in a similar way?

Comment: maybe [How to make weak linking work with GCC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274753/how-to-make-weak-linking-work-with-gcc) can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not been able to hook into the dynamic linker, but providing weak symbols helped me out like this:

```
extern "C"
char * __attribute__ ((weak)) mxArrayToUTF8String( mxArray const * array )
{
  return mxArrayToString( array ) ;
}
```