# error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void': Weak case

Tags: c, syntax

I have a portion of the code as:

```
__weak  void TimingDelay_Decrement(void) {

}
```

and it keeps throwing up the captioned error. I checked the web and couldn't find relevant content for the `__weak` case. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `__weak` is probably specific to a certain compiler.  Maybe you're using a different compiler.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274753/how-to-make-weak-linking-work-with-gcc

Comment: `__weak` is not a keyword of standard C.  I have only guesses as to what it might mean to whatever compiler your code was originally written for.  The compiler you are using now doesn't know, either.  It might work simply to remove the `__weak`, or to `#define` it to nothing, but it would be wise to first figure out what it was supposed to accomplish.

Comment: I'm running this in the Atollic TrueStudio IDE, which says "Built on Eclipse, CDT, GCC and GDB. Simple to extend."

Comment: Difference between [`#include <file.h>` and `#include "file.h"`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html)

Comment: @P__J__ - I think you didn't see the comment I was commenting on. It's not related to the __weak definition. It's about the file not being found. Look at 3 comments above this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is ARM Cortex gcc toolchain so the `__weak` is a definition of `__attribute__((weak))`.

The easiest way to add is to amend the `gcc` command line arguments: `-D__weak=__attribute__((weak))`